# How can I edit data in used for execution in Gem5

Tags: gem5

I want to edit data that is used in thread contexts in Gem5 in order to simulate an effect of approximation.

I have traced data manipulation by SimpleBaseCPU all the way till copyRegs() -> set****RegFlat() for x86 architecture.

Only to see that set***RegFlat() [*** stands for Int/Float/CC] are purely virtual functions. Are they implemented anywhere ? Or is this a dead end ?

Comment: Have you tried 'grep -nr " set[A-Z][a-z]*RegFlat" src/'? I find many implementations in multiple files.

Comment: I have edited readFloatRegOperandBits() and setFloatRegOperandBits() as floating point data is what I am trying to edit. I used some of the functions and opClass to make sure I am only changing data for Memory Stores and FloatMemRead. But the data at the output doesnot change.

Comment: I'm unable to provide further input. You should try asking this question in the mailing list, if you haven't already.

Comment: Am I supposed to get an invite or something ? I got to the point where the webpage said "Your subscription request has been received, and will soon be acted upon. Depending on the configuration of this mailing list, your subscription request may have to be first confirmed by you via email, or approved by the list moderator. If confirmation is required, you will soon get a confirmation email which contains further instructions"

Comment: I don't recall, but I don't think so. Try writing the question to the mailing list and seeing if it is properly shown (after a few minutes) at https://www.mail-archive.com/gem5-users@gem5.org/.